# Disabling/replacing paperclip in Spree Commerce

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, paperclip, spree

I have a pre-existing CDN with images for Spree::Products. I already imported the products but the pictures are yet to be somehow taken care of.

Sure, I can import all 400000 images, but that would take really, really long and caused duplication.

Is there any way to replace paperclip with some simple mechanism that would just serve existing pictures? I want all the pictures to be transferred through the Rails app, because otherwise it would cause unsecure content warnings on a SSL site...

So I'm thinking this: Can I just override the paperclip gem and serve existing images instead? Or can I replace paperclip entirely? Or can I do something about this at all?

Additional info: I have a database of all urls of all images with their PN/SKU/ID relations.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple mechanism to replace Paperclip.  You should just be able to code your own solution, override any calls to paperclips methods to call your method pretty easily enough though.  It just may be a bit time consuming, and possibly more time consuming than it would be for you to just deal with importing the images instead.